# FB API call to canvas width always gives zero

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using the Facebook Graph API (javascript one).

I am trying to get the canvas size using the function FB.Canvas.getPageInfo()["clientWidth"];

But it always bloody returns zero, why?

Maybe its when I call the function? Maybe its meant to be zero, but I dont think so because if it was I would not be able to see my HTML inside the canvas because the width is zero right?

My code:

```
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>

    <div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function()
      {
        FB.init( {appId: 'MYAPPID', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true} );

      };
      (function() 
          {
            var e = document.createElement('script'); 
            e.async = true;
            e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
            document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);

          }());

</script>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
     alert( FB.Canvas.getPageInfo()["clientWidth"] );  // PS other SDK calls do work likelogin so I know my app id etc are correct
-->
</script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

> the function assigned to
>   window.fbAsyncInit is run as soon as
>   the Facebook JS SDK is loaded. Any
>   code you want to run after the SDK is
>   loaded should be placed within this
>   function and after the call to
>   FB.init().

now try this.

```
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>

<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function()
      {
        FB.init( {appId: 'MYAPPID', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true} );
        alert( FB.Canvas.getPageInfo()["clientWidth"] );

      };
      (function() 
          {
            var e = document.createElement('script'); 
            e.async = true;
            e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
            document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);

          }());

</script>
</body>
```